# Hosting a Cloud Foundry Node.js application

Tags: node.js, hosting, cloud-foundry

I have a Node.js app that I'm building and deploying to Cloud Foundry. I know that Cloud Foundry dose not allow pointing a domain name to it's server, but I'm just wondering if there are other options to deploy a production version under a unique domain name instead of the standard app.cloudfoundry.com.

I read somewhere that Cloud Foundry would be offered as a service with some hosting providers, but can't seems to find any yet.

Thanks.

Comment: CloudFoundry.com should offer custom domains etc when the commercial/production version goes live before the end of the year. Other providers like AppFog do offer CloudFoundry hosting already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Andy Piper's Comment > "CloudFoundry.com should offer custom domains etc when the commercial/production version goes live before the end of the year. Other providers like AppFog do offer CloudFoundry hosting already."

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PWS) 
https://run.pivotal.io/ that let's you deploy apps with cf and offers a domain managment where you can add private domain and map the route of your cfapps.io domain to your DNS

For instance if you want to add a route like this
***`example.yourdomain.com`*** to your cloudfoundry app

Create a new domain:

`cf create-domain 'MY ORG' yourdomain.com`

and then you can create a mapping from the app to your DNS record on CF

`cf map-route APP_NAME yourdomain.com --hostname example`

Then in your DNS manager update the record to point to your app cfapps.io domain

**DNS Record**

`example  ==> myCFapp.cfapps.io`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

I bought a debian vps and installed everything i needed on it. redis, mongodb, node, git. there's also node-jitsu that looks pretty good if you want to host your db at a cloud provider.